# Does beginTransaction() work with prepare()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
$achievement_name = $db->prepare("SELECT `achievement_name` FROM `achievement_names` WHERE `id` = :a_id");
$achievement_name->bindValue(":a_id",$r['achievement_id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$achievement_desc = $db->prepare("SELECT `achievement_desc` FROM `achievement_names` WHERE `id` = :a_id");
$achievement_desc->bindValue(":a_id",$r['achievement_id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$achievement_image = $db->prepare("SELECT `image` FROM `achievement_names` WHERE `id` = :a_id");
$achievement_image->bindValue(":a_id",$r['achievement_id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->commit();
```

Is this possible with PDO? To have the $db->prepare() and bindValue() functions and then committing them? It doesn't seem to be working for me, because they are returning bool(false).

Comment: what about *executing* your queries?

Comment: Doesn't `$db->commit();` do that?

Comment: Huh, would you look at that, when I execute my queries, it actually works :D

Comment: Every operator does its own job: execute executes the query. Commit commits a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction is using for consistent read or write data. "Preparing" doesn't read or write any data.

So, the answer is: Yes, beginTransaction() work properly with prepare(), but it useless.